# typescript Constraining generics by compatible property types

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a function which updates `property` in one object with some other `property` from another object

like

```
function compareAndUpdate<T, S>(target: T, source: S, targrtKey: keyof T, sourceKey: keyof S): boolean {
    // some processing
    target[targrtKey] = source[sourceKey]; // this line gives error 

    // some more processing

}
```

I know that I can fix error by using `<any>`

`target` and `source` are of distinct types. `T` and `S` may or may not have proprieties with same name , but `T` can have a property whose type is same as some other property in `S`

Is there a way to guaranty that `typeof target[targrtKey] === typeof source[sourceKey]` so that compiler catch error when incompatible property keys are passed.

**Edit:** Submitted upstream feature request [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18467)

Comment: The error does make sense. The compiler gives the error below because it doesn't know which type it can infer. Compare and update functions can be written otherwise to really update the object when a change is detected and to return a new one...

Comment: @GieSpaepen I have no issues with error.
I want to guaranty that compiler should catch when incompatible property keys are passed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, in fact, do this.  Here's how:

```
function compareAndUpdate<T, TK extends keyof T, SK extends string, S extends Record<SK,T[TK]>>(target: T, source: S, targetKey: TK, sourceKey: SK): boolean {
    // some processing
    target[targetKey] = source[sourceKey]; // okay
    return true;
}
```

Let's unpack that declaration:

- `T` is the type of the target
- `TK` is the type of the target key (so it needs to extend `keyof T`).  Note that `T[TK]` is the type of the target *value* for that key.
- `SK` is the type of the source key (so it needs to extend `string`)
- `S` is the type of source, which needs to have `SK` as a key, and any value you get from that key needs to be assignable to `T[TK]`.  `Record<SK,T[TK]>` is a type with keys of type `SK`, and values of type `T[TK]`.  So when `S extends Record<SK,T[TK]>`, we're saying that we want `S` to be any type where `S[SK]` is the same as `T[TK]`.

Let's try it:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
const person: Person = { name: 'Stephen King', age: 69 };

interface Book {
  title: string;
  authorName: string;
}
const book: Book = { title: 'The Running Man', authorName: 'Richard Bachman' };

compareAndUpdate(book, person, 'authorName', 'name'); // okay
compareAndUpdate(book, person, 'authorName', 'age');  // error, number not assignable to string
compareAndUpdate(person, book, 'authorName', 'name'); // error, 'name' property not found
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: A very interesting solution, didn't think it was possible,

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the same type if you want them to be equal :

```
function compareAndUpdate<T>(target: T, source: T, targrtKey: keyof T, sourceKey: keyof T): boolean { return true; }
```

Another version would be to guarantee that no property of `S` is not present in `T`

```
function compareAndUpdate<T extends S, S>(target: T, source: S, targrtKey: keyof T, sourceKey: keyof S): boolean { return true; }
```

When you use you will get errors if someone tries to put on the target, properties not part of `T`

```
//Valid
compareAndUpdate({ test: "S"}, { test: "DD" }, "test", "test")
compareAndUpdate({ test: "S", bla : 0}, { test: "DD" }, "test", "test")
//Invalied, bla does not exist on T
compareAndUpdate({ test: "S"}, { test: "DD", bla : 0 }, "test", "test")
```

I use object literals for simplicity, but it will work with classes as well, if S contains fields in the class :

```
class Dog {
  name: string;
  bark(): void{}
}
// OK
compareAndUpdate(new Dog(), {name: "" }, "name", "name");
// NOK
compareAndUpdate(new Dog(), {isAGodBoy: "" }, "name", "name");
```

Comment: Thing is both `target` and `source` are of distinct types. `T` and `S` may or may not have proprieties with same name , but `T` can have a property whose type is same as some other property in `S`

Comment: @AbdulKareem Unfortunately I don't see a way to achieve this with two completely unrelated types

Comment: Thanks Any way I will open an issue on github for this

Comment: I don't think this warrants an GitHub issue; see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46221474/2887218)